# How to relieve pressure to behind caliper piston?

Tags: brakes, disk-brakes

95 Integra LS 4-door: I am having great difficulty pushing in the caliper piston: necessary to position the rear brake caliper.

As the brake fluid system is closed, I would think that opening the system up temporarily would allow the piston.   Is this line of thinking correct?  Can the closed system be opened in the engine bay?

I'd like to dribbling brake fluid through the bleed screw.

Excerpt from manual:

[image]

Comment: I think this is the same issue as your other question.  This is clearly a "wind back system" and you'll need a wind back tool to reset the piston back to its starting point.  You cannot  simply push these back into the caliper.  Please delete this question and update your other one as this is the same issue.

Comment: I don't understand your question. First you ask about "pushing in the caliper piston," then you say "I'd like to dribbling brake fluid through the bleed screw" which isn't the same thing (and doesn't make grammatic sense), then you include an image of brake bleeding instructions, something yet different. What problem are you trying to solve? If it's pressure within the system, I'd suspect the bleed hole (between the master cylinder mworking chamber and the brake fluid reservoir) is plugged.